# Does NSXMLParser eat blank values?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsxmlparser

I have some XML which looks like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<methodResponse>
    <params>
        <param>
            <value><array><data>
                <value><array><data>
                    <value><dateTime.iso8601>20100508T14:49:56</dateTime.iso8601></value>
                    <value><string></string></value>
                    <value><string>comment</string></value>
                    <value><string></string></value>
                    <value><string>Milestone milestone1 deleted</string></value>
                    <value><int>1</int></value>
                </data></array></value>
            </data></array></value>
        </param>
    </params>
</methodRepsonse>
```

NSXMLParser seems to not be giving any data back for the blank values resulting in an array with 4 items in it instead of 6.

Is there anything I can do to NSXMLParser to make it return an empty string for the blank values so that I can maintain the order of the data when it is returned?

Answer (score 1):

So after whipping up a quick sample with a delegate that just prints out what's happening during parsing I don't see anything at all wrong with what's being parsed.

I suspect however that you're relying on an incorrect expectation that between calls to `didStartElement...` and `didEndElement...` you should get a `foundCharacters...` call with an empty string?  My question is based on the way you phrased the title of your question because there's no such thing as a "blank value."  Either there is a value, or there isn't.

Imagine instead your XML contained <string/> instead of the exactly equivalent <string></string>.  You still get start/end notifications.

You should be creating your `NSMutableString` (presumably the type that you're using for your <string> elements) in `didStartElement...` when <string> is found, appending to that string IF `foundCharacters...` is called (it can get called more than once with the value in chunks), and tossing it into your array when it's done on `didEndElement...`.

If you really want to be more robust, you'll also be wanting detect an error condition if you find the start of a new element before your string ends, assuming that it is in fact an error for you.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure I understand your problem here. NSXMLParser would at least report the beginning and end of the  elements. Would that not be enough the get them in the right order?